# Tomar dos números después del punto solamente

Tags: c#

Como puedo cortar esta serie de números y solo tener dos mas después del punto decimal.

```
 3.00.11089.17391
```

Que quede asi:

```
3.00
```

Comment: Los números los almacenas como string?

Comment: Asi es, como string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un [split](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) puedes hacer eso:

```c#
string Numero = "3.00.11089.17391";
string NumeroOK = Numero.Split('.')[0];
NumeroOK += Numero.Split('.')[1].substring(0, 2);
Console.WriteLine(NumeroOK);
```